# Repeat same method and using new value of one parameter

Tags: java

I'm trapped within this certain predicament of mine and I would gladly accept any suggestion. So here it is:

I'm currently working in a method where a certain variable is assigned a specific value in the beginning part of the method. During the course of the method, that variable is used as a parameter by an external component which basically returns a result code. In one of those result codes, I have to change the value of the prior mentioned variable and repeat the whole process using the new value. The concept is as follows but I have simplified it as much as possible:

```
public void myMethod (String args[]) {
    String server;

    server = "some value";

    switch (someExternalOperation(server)) {
    case 1:
        //process....
        break;
    case 2:
        server = "new value";
        //repeat myMethod using new value of server String variable
        break;
    }
}

public int someExternalOperation (String str) {
    //after several operation
    return 1; //example purposes
}
```

By the way, I have checked and researched things like goto and other alternative. I may have overlooked some results and ended up asking here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: And what is your problem? What does not work? But it seems that you want to pass `server` as a parameter to `myMethod`.

Answer (score 3):

One simple option is to have a private overload taking the `server` parameter - then you can call it recursively:

```
public void myMethod(String args[]) {
    myMethod(args, "some value");
}

private void myMethod(String[] args, String server) {
    switch (someExternalOperation(server)) {
        case 1:
            // process....
            break;
        case 2:
            myMethod(args, "new value");
            break;
    }
}
```

You need to make sure that isn't going to recurse infinitely, of course.

Another option would be to just have a loop inside your method:

```
public void myMethod (String args[]) {
    String server = "some value";

    while (true) { // Or ideally a different condition...
        switch (someExternalOperation(server)) {
            case 1:
                // process....
                // Done! Exit the method...
                return;
            case 2:
                server = "new value";
                // We'll now continue to the next iteration of the loop
                break;
            default:
                // ?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've thought of recursion but the actual code is too long and it's not efficient to use it for this case. Anyway thanks for the help. We've already figured out how to address this problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Uzi: I don't see how the length of the code would be relevant to whether or not recursion is viable... But there's always the loop case otherwise. Please make sure that when you ask future questions, you include all relevant information (and things you've already tried) to avoid wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way instead to address. Thanks everyone for reading. I'll just simply use the external operation and check if it will return case 2.

```
public void myMethod (String args[]) {
    String server;

    server = "some value";

    if (someExternalOperation(server) == 2)
        server = "new value";


    switch (someExternalOperation(server)) {
    case 1:
        //process....
        break;
    }
}

public int someExternalOperation (String str) {
    //after several operation
    return 1; //example purposes
}
```

Thanks for your help anyway.